# Integration with G Suite

Tags: civimail

I wonder what is the best configuration for CiviCRM if it is supposed to serve an organisation which uses G Suite?
Can I use any hosting company that handles Drupal?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What type of integration are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, integration with Gmail, Contacts, Tasks, Agenda, Drive - to start with :)

Answer (score 4):

**Choosing a webhost:**

Sounds like you are new to CiviCRM and you are starting a new site.  To your second - easier question - you can use any host for CiviCRM - if you have the budget - I would [go with an expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) that can implement everything to meet your needs on a VPS.  Otherwise if you are on a tight budget - these are two shared web hosts that I recommend (In No Particular Order):

1. [CiviHosting](https://civihosting.com/) - [Supporting Partner of CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/providers/CiviHosting)
2. [Namecheap Stellar Business](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/shared/) -  Not a partner of CiviCRM

I have used the above for different deployments and have been very happy. [Alternatively - these are the requirements for CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/), choose whatever hosting company you are comfortable or have experience with and make sure they meet the requirements for CiviCRM, any extensions you may use, and your CMS. In addition - I would recommend that you choose a web host that supports PHP imagemagick library.

**CiviCRM - GSuite Integration**

There has been a bit of work on this and I recommend you check these extensions out:

1. [CiviGmail Integration with Gmail](https://civicrm.org/blog/deepaksrivastava/civigmail-integration-with-gmail)
2. [Google Groups CiviCRM Integration](https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-groups-civicrm-integration)
3. [Google Apps Sync](https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-apps-sync)
4. [CiviCRM - Google Script/Drive Integration](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2016/10/using-civicrm-with-google-scriptgoogle-drive-with-the-new-civiservice-google-script-library/)
5. [Integrating Email Client into CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/integrating-email-client-into-civicrm)
6. [Inbound Email](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/)

Lastly - with all external integration - outlook, gmail, etc. - you should focus on getting your staff to use CiviCRM first. For example, don't place an item on your google calendar first - add it to Civi first - then you can have events assigned to you sync or be sent to your calendar. I am not sure what Google Drive integration would even look like - can't help you there.

Ill also say this - take baby steps - and you will learn how best to implement this for your organization. Maybe tight integration with G Suite isn't the best use of your time - maybe creating an interface in which Civi and G Suite are easily accessible from each other is an easier option. In the end - practice makes perfect.

Comment: There is also the inbuilt "inbound email" which has sufficed for a number of our clients needs: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/ (if you mentioned this and i skipped over it my apologies)

Comment: Nope but added @petednz-fuzion thanks!